# Read from database and load the values of radio buttons in asp.net server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want my web page to do in this way: when web page loads, all the radio button values should be fetched from database and shown in web page. This is a part of my ".cshtml" code:

```
<div class="radiobtn">
    <label for="koobideh">select</label>
    <input type="radio" id="koobideh" name="0" value="004" runat="server">
</div>
```

Here is a part of my ".cs" file:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    string sql = "SELECT foodId FROM [reservation] WHERE userId = '" + UserId + "'" +
                                         "AND date = '" + date + "'";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            string foodid = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("foodId"));
            ???????????????
        } 
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

So when the web page is loaded for the first time, the input radios should be fetched from database and loaded in the correct place.

My first try was this:

```
Request.Form["0"] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("foodId"));
```

But this is impossible since Request.Form is "ReadOnly". How can I do such a thing?

I have the "name" properties of input radios. I want to read the value of each group from database and make the radio as checked in the front side.

Comment: use parameterized query to avoid SQL injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This May help. Here is an example of how you can show the chosen `radio` based on the retrieved value from DataBase.

[image]

**This is the `.cshtml` code:**

```
<label>
    <input asp-for="Gender" type="radio" value="male">
    <label for="male">Male</label>
</label>
<label>
    <input asp-for="Gender" type="radio" value="female">
    <label for="female">Female </label>
</label>
```

**in the `.cs file`**

```
    [BindProperty]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        Gender = await GetPersonGender(personId);
        return Page();

    }


    //This Method to extract the Gender value of a person from DB.
    private async Task<string> GetPersonGender( string personId)
    {
        string personGender = "";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using var command = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE PersonId = @id", connection);
            
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", personId);
            using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                personGender = reader["Gender"].ToString();
            }
                
            
        }
        return personGender;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. It doesn't load the Gender value to the radio buttons on the page.

Comment: it will not if you are just copying the code, because that require a table named Person and a Column named PersonId and another Column Named Gender. so, you should configure your database first if you want to use the code above. 
or just replace the `await GetPersonGender(personId);` with `"male"` and sometimes with `"female'`.
@Nastaran

Comment: I was wrong in some lines.  Finally it works. Thank you so much.